# Bind self-hosted WCF service to subdomain

Tags: c#, wcf

I have 2 instances of a self-hosted wcf service. One dev and one acceptance.
These need to be bound to 'dev.example.com/TestService' and 'acc.example.com/TestService'.

When I start the first service, it binds to 'http://+:80/TestService'.
Requests for both environments are received on the first instance.
And when the second instance is started, it can't bind anymore.

Is there a way to configure the servicehost to only bind on specific subdomain?

Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="TestProject.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="WebServiceBehavior">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://dev.example.com/TestService" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TestProject.ITestService">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WebServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Code:

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof (TestService));
_host.Open();
```

Comment: Are you talking about namespace registration (URLACLs)?

Comment: Yes I am. When staring the ServiceHost, it does an automatic namespace registration.

Comment: Well you could whip out netsh on a post build/deploy task and remove the existing http://+:80 registration and then add your new URLS in

Comment: The problem is at runtime. On _host.Open() the servicehost tries to take control of 'http://+:80/TestService'. If the registration isn't already made, it will make it on the fly and use it to host the service.   So changing the URLACL post build/deploy won't help. the servicehost will detect that it's requered registration isn't there and make it.